# IF, ELSE IF, ELSE com diferenças de datas em PHP

Tags: php

Estou tentando uma condição em `ELSE IF` que está dando errado, já fiz algumas coisas bastante semelhantes e realmente não sei o que é...

Tenho uma tabela em meu sistema, aonde exibe algumas informações para o usuário, dentro dela, possui um campo chamado **pagamento**, tive que colocar esse campo como input do tipo `text`, por que o usuário pode colocar ou *"PENDENTE"* ou colocar a *data do pagamento*, e por isso acabei deixando o input como text.

Outro campo se chama  **emissao** aonde é do `type date` e preciso fazer a comparação de dias com esse campo.

> As condições estão funcionando, menos o `ELSE IF.`

Preciso que se o campo **emissao** passar de 30 dias e o campo **pagamento** estiver pendente, ele use uma certa class...

Tentei fazer isso, pegando a diferença de anos/dias/meses da data da **emissao** comparada a data atual, e joguei em uma condição.

**Vamos para o código:**

```
<?php

                $sql = "SELECT * FROM emissao_nf";

                $resultado = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

                while ($cont = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)) {

                $prazo = new DateTime ($cont['emissao']);      // Data do banco em DateTime
                $hoje = new DateTime();                        // Data atual em "DateTime"
                $intervalo = $prazo->diff( $hoje );             // Pegando a diferença de anos, meses e dias

                if(substr_count($cont['pagamento'], 'PEN') > 0){ 
                $mostra="status-p bg-warning"; //Pendente, amarelo

                }elseif(substr_count($cont['pagamento'], 'PEN') > 0 && $intervalo->m >= '1') {
                $mostra="status-p bg-danger";  //Passou 30 dias e está pendente, vermelho

                }else{
                $mostra="status-p bg-primary"; // Data de pagamento, azul
                }

                echo"
                <tr>
                <td><span class='".$mostra."'>".$cont['pagamento']."</span></td>
                </tr> 
                "; ?>
```

O `ELSE IF` não funciona, não da erro na página e nem nada... Alguém pode me ajudar? Acho errado eu estar utilizando um `type text` para datas, porém, não sei o que eu posso fazer.

*Neste print, a ideia seria que estivesse "PENDENTE" mas em vermelho... Hoje é dia 09/06/2020*

[image: PRINT]

Comment: O seu `elseif` nunca vai acontecer, pois caso a primeira condição dele `substr_count($cont['pagamento'], 'PEN') > 0` é exatamente a condição do `if`, portanto vai entrar no `if` antes de entrar no `elseif`. Coloca o if como elseif e o elseif como if.

Comment: Olá @Benilson, obrigado pela resposta, vou tentar!

Comment: Era isso mesmo, muito obrigado! não me atentei a isso, as próximas vezes não irei errar mais, agradeço e uma ótima semana.

Comment: Feliz em ter ajudado.